# jQuery datepicker how to execute a function when it loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following script which works fine:

```
$(".txtDate").datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "+0:+1",
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function(dateText, obj){
        test_function( dateText );
    }
} );

$('.txtDate').datepicker( "setDate" , new Date() );

function test_function( strDate ) {
    alert( strDate );
}
```

It `datepicker` enables the HTML control `.txtDate`, it displays todays' date in `.txtDate` by default when the webpage loads, and it also displays an alert if I choose another date from the `datepicker`.

My question is, how do I get the `datepicker` to execute `test_function` when the page loads so it displays the default date in an alert set by the `datepicker` when the page loads?

The alert `test_function` is just a test to see when the `datepicker` executes other functions, the end result will be a lot more complex.

Also, I have a widget based website, which lets people add many of the same widget on the page at once, which means I will have many `.txtDate` controls.  So I can't just get the value of `.txtDate`, I will need to find the closest one based on $(this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to call this `test_function()` function in page load, so you can able to get the datepicker default value in page load like,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
   $('.txtDate').datepicker( "setDate" , new Date() );     
   test_function();
});

function test_function() {
   alert( $("#txtDate").val() );
 }
</script>
```

You dont need to pass any parameter values to this js function.

Comment: Please see the end of my question, your solution will not work.

Comment: So you have many `.txtDate` controls in your page. This `.txtDate` control should be in table/div. so you can get table/div _id_. You will use **Closest / find** to get the _.txtDate_ values like `$("#tblId").find('.txtDate').val();`

Comment: try above one, Suppose its not working for you, add your sample `html` codes with your question...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 function addLoadEvent(func) {
       var oldonload = window.onload;
       if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
         window.onload = func;
       } else {
         window.onload = function() {
           if (oldonload) {
             oldonload();
           }
           func();
         }
       }
       }

    addLoadEvent(incompleteForm);

    function incompleteForm()
    {
       alert( $("#txtDate").val() );
    }
```